# Styling text elements with background

Tags: html, css

I would like to know, if it is possible to style some text, as show below:

[image]

At first, you see the text is using a `<h1>` tag. It has background color set, and also `max-width` property to break this into two lines.

And below you see the same text, but background looks better and like i want.

My question is: is this possible ? We see some white space between words, and i'm not sure if this can be done, without breaking text into 2 `<h1>` tags, like:

```
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<h1>WITH GRADIENT</h1>
```

Thanks for advice.

That's what i tried:

```
 h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(40,138,187,0.8) 0, rgba(128,28,75,0.8) 100%);
    padding: 10px 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    max-width: 300px
}
```

Comment: I don't think so it is possible text into two different <h1> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this property `box-decoration-break: clone;`

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #9d7f71;
box-decoration-break: clone;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  width: auto;
line-height: 1.4;
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADING WITH GRADIENT</h1>
```

Comment: I need to add bigger line-height in my case, but looks promissing - will test and reply.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```css
 h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(40,138,187,0.8) 0, rgba(128,28,75,0.8) 100%);
    padding: 10px 18px;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
    font-size: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    max-width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.75;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading With Gradient</h1>
```

Comment: This will not render white break between words.

Comment: Sorry, just copied your code, and looks good, i will test and reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `span` tag, check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/3aknLe58/1/)

**HTML**

```
<h1>
  <span>HEADING</span><br>
  <span>WITH GRADIENT</span>
</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
h1 > span{background: #D99680;}
</style>
```

Comment: With <span> it's very easy to do. But it's part of CMS, and css shoudl be used to make this simple.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div{
position:relative;
}
h1:first-child{
background-color:brown;
position:absolute;
}
h1:nth-child(2){
background-color:brown;
position:absolute;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>HEADING</h1>
<h1>WITH GRADIENT</h1>
  <div>
```

Comment: I wrote, that text should NOT be in 2 <h1> tags.

Comment: OK OK fine I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

The trick is 1) to make the h1 an inline element, and 2) put it in a container that has a larger line height than it.

```css
header {line-height:1.5; max-width:300px}
h1 {display:inline; text-transform:uppercase; background:#944;}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Heading with&nbsp;gradient</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: yeah, but you used <br> - and as i said, i'm not able to insert anything else, than <h1>

Comment: There is no way to tell CSS to put the first word of an element on one line and the rest of the words on another. You will have to use "tricks" such as inserting a br. Or, the way I did it in my edit. I think you're mking it unnecessarily hard on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
mark{
  background:#a47a67;

  }
```

```html
<h1><mark>HEADING</mark></h1>
<h1><mark>WITH GRADIENT</mark></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<h1>with Gradient</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1{text-transform: uppercase;background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(40,138,187,0.8) 0, rgba(128,28,75,0.8) 100%);padding: 10px 18px;font-size: 60px;letter-spacing: 5px;max-width: 300px}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Lalji Tadhani** answer helped me.
But in he's code we have `display:inline` and then max-width will not work.
Solution for this is to add parent to `<h1>` tag and add `max-width:50%` in my case.

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Heading with Gradient</h1>
</div>

.parent { max-width:50% }
.parent h1 {

color: white;
font-size: 44px;
font-family: Poppins;
font-weight: 300;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0 10px;
letter-spacing: 5px;
width: auto;
line-height: 1.9;
display: inline;
background: red;
/* important */
box-decoration-break: clone;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

I think, that is best soluton. Thanks ALL for resolwing this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #9d7f71;
  margin-top:10px;
box-decoration-break: clone;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  width: auto;
height:100px;
line-height: 1.4;
display: inline;

}
```

```html
<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;HEADING WITH &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;GRADIENT&nbsp;&nbsp;</h1>
```